# Remove last n chars from a column in a CSV?

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv, openoffice-calc

Is there a way in microsoft excel or open office calc to remove the last n chars from a field.

Lets say all fields in one column are 31 chars long and I want to remove the last 6 chars.

Is there an easy way with excel or calc to do this?

Comment: are they numeric or text fields?

Comment: This is a text field.  And I could write a simple script to do it but would rather use an application to click a few buttons which is why I asked for this type of solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your data is in A1, you could put the following formula in B1 (or elsewhere):

```
=LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-6)
```

If you want a fixed result rather than a calculated one, you could then copy the result and use 'paste as values'.

Comment: better than my solution - i was going for numeric files and doing some division and rounding down

Comment: Is this excel?  Doesn't work in open office calc.

Comment: Did work in excel, how would I apply that to all rows though?  I have the formula as "=LEFT($K2,LEN($K2)-6)" which worked for one cell but I want to apply this to 100k records.  I know i can drag down the column but thats a lot of dragging for 100k rows

Comment: @Chris, select a cell in a column that has values (K would work in your case), press `Ctrl`+`Down arrow`. You should be at the bottom of your data. Select the bottom cell in the column you want to fill with the formula, press `Shift`+`Ctrl`+`Up arrow`, then press `Ctrl`+`D`.

Comment: For OpenOffice, just replace the comma with a semicolon: =LEFT(A1;LEN(A1)-6)